# When i enter my numbers only the min is read not max

Tags: java, arrays, loops, max, min

In my code i am trying to enter 10 numbers which it does and output the min number which it does and output the max number which it doesn't, I have tried changing the < and > in the max algorithm but it doesn't work. Does anyone have any advice on what i should do ?
Thanks in advance

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Results {
    public static void main (String args []){

        //Variables
        //Set up Array
        int arr[]; //Declare Array
        arr = new int [10];
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;;

        //Input
        //Set up loop

        //Quiz 1
        for(int i = 0; i<10;i=i+1){
        arr[i]=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a number for quiz 1"));

        }


        //Minimum


        for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
            if (arr[i] < min) {
                min = arr[i];
            }
            }

        //Maximum


        for (int i = 0; i > max; i00) {
            if (arr[i] > max) {
            max = arr[i];
            }
            }

        //Output
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The minimum is " +min);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The maximum is " +max);







        }



    }
```

Comment: Could you post code that compiles? `for (int i = 0; i > max; i00)`. Also this is certainly not the for-condition you are looking for (for both loops).

Comment: the code does compile

Comment: I doubt that `for (int i = 0; i > max; i00)` compiles.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop checks for min/max in condition which is wrong. So if you have numbers like 1,2,0 and you are trying to find min max with existing code, you loop for min will be:

```
i =0, i<MAX integer value
assign min as 1
i=1, i<1
it will exit and you wont get 0 as output
```

Same holds for loop with max condition checks.

Change your for loop as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     if (arr[i] < min) {
         min = arr[i];
     }
}

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > max) {
         max = arr[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of just handing someone code, could you at least explain what is different and why?

Comment: I agree with @Takendarkk _"Your for loop check for min/max in condition which is wrong"_ But why? If the op ask this question it's certainly because it's not obvious for him to see what's wrong. Try to put some efforts to explain why and making it a better answer (with small examples or explanations).

Comment: Thanks ir worked perfectly, but could you explain what you did.Thanks OP

Comment: @JoeCommons i updated your for loop conditions and removed min or max comparison from them and instead using size of whole array so to inspect each element within array. Btw you could combine both the loops into one.

Comment: ... or you could get rid of both loops and compute/update min and max when you ask the input.